# Django template parses string as integer

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-templates

I have a list which looks like the following:

```
[(2,'09-07-2014')]
```

when I access this list at the client side I can access it using:

```
{% for item in list %}
console.log( {{ item.0 }} + ' and ' + {{ item.1 }} )
{% endfor %}
```

Problem is `item.0` returns `2` as it should but `item.1` returns `-2012` as `9-7-2014` in integer representation would compute to `-2012`.

How do I make the client side script realize this is a string not an integer.

Below is the whole listing of the code:

```
chartdata= getChartData(request.session['userphone'])
log.debug(chartdata)
return render(request,'users.html',{'table':table,'topics':request.session['topics'],'profilepic':request.session['profilepic'],'chartdata':chartdata,'time':str(time.time())})
```

The `log.debug(chartdata)` returns the following in my log file:

```
[11/Jul/2013 18:02:15] DEBUG [karnadash.views:179] [(85, '2013-07-08'), (120, '2013-07-08'), (205, '2013-07-08'), (305, '2013-07-08'), (405, '2013-07-08'), (505, '2013-07-08'), (547, '2013-07-09'), (564, '2013-07-09'), (581, '2013-07-09'), (607, '2013-07-09'), (624, '2013-07-09'), (659, '2013-07-09'), (694, '2013-07-09'), (711, '2013-07-09'), (737, '2013-07-09'), (754, '2013-07-09'), (771, '2013-07-09'), (871, '2013-07-09')]
```

Comment: As far as I know, Django does not try to interpret that string to an integer in this case. That never happened to me, anyway. That interpretion probably happens somewhere else. As you have tagged this with 'javascript' even though no JS is involved in your queston, I'm pointing a finger. ;-)

Comment: Ill show you my data exactly as it appears in my log file.

Comment: I don't doubt that your log file says `-2012`. I doubt that the above code makes that happen. It must happen before. Python will happily make strings out of the integers in this case. But it will not make integers out of strings, especially not the string '09-07-2014' which is an invalid integer in Python's eyes.

Comment: It's the `console.log` call that converts your value to int. You must cast it to string (`String({{ obj }})`) before. If you just type your `{{ item.1 }}` in your template, it's shown correctly

Comment: See, told you is was the javascript. :-)

Comment: check Daniel answer (damn I could have gone for that as well). You don't wrap it into quotes nor tell js that's a string. So you just 'put there 3 numbers with a minus sign between', which gets evaluated

Comment: @Samuele I do not understand still. String({{item.1}} also does not work :(

Comment: That's because my js skills are awful. `'{{ item.1 }}'` is enough to tell js it's dealing with a string

Comment: @SilentPro: Tthe first item is an integer, so Javascript will try to make it all integers, I think. https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django is not doing this, the Javascript is, because you have not told the JS that you are dealing with a string. If you were to look at the HTML source, you would see exactly what is happening - it will look something like this:

```
console.log( 2 + ' and ' + 09-07-2014 )
```

There aren't any quotes around the date value, because you haven't put any there, so JS thinks it's an expression. It's easily solved:

```
console.log( '{{ item.0 }}' + ' and ' + '{{ item.1 }}' )
```

Or, even better, since JS doesn't care about the fact that they're separate items in Django:

```
console.log( '{{ item.0 }} and {{ item.1 }}' )
```

Comment: Ohh. Works perfect! Thanks. Dunno whhy I didnt think of the fact that templates get resolved before the js kicks in.